# Overheating SSD

Tags: debian, manjaro, ssd

I just installed ManjaroLinux 18.0.4 Illyria (`cat /etc/lsb-release`) with XFCE and with 4.19.69 Kernel (`uname -r`) on a MacBook Air 2013 -- I updated the packages and settled usual minor issues with broadcom drivers.

I have a problem that persists, namely that, `sensors` gives me `TH0a: +76.2°C` (I can also feel it on my legs) without any load (`top` shows that no swap is used, 1.79G of free memory, and `df -h` shows more than 70G free space, same for `iotop` or `iostats`).

I believe `TH0a` refers to a sensor in my SSD (Apple SSD SD0128) and I believe the temperature is way too high -- especially if I compare it to the CPU temperature, which is 20° below).

Have you specific manips in mind that should be carried in order to address it? Let me know if you need more information.

Note: 1) Manjaro is the only OS installed on the MacBook (no dual boots). 2) Debian Stretch worked fine, a month before, on the very same laptop, 3) I can confirm that fans are working.

Thanks already!

PS.: I encountered a similar issue when upgrading from Debian Stretch to Buster, and that was the ultimate trigger for switching to Manjaro.

PPS.: The SSD does not seem to be in cause according to SMART tools. I wonder how much it might be related to the update to the Kernel 4.19.

Comment: Is a process `fstrim` running? It might be doing a discard on all the unused disc blocks, causing the ssd to work a bit.

Comment: 'ps -A | grep fstrim' gives nothing.

Comment: Can you check for actual I/O with `iostat`, `dstat` etc.?